# How to get value of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$ without using Stirling-formula?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The problem $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$$ was a for-fun-only exercise given by our Calculus Professor. I was able to solve it quite easily with the use of the Stirling-formula, but can't figure out if it can be done in a different way, possibly by brute force spiced with recognizing the Euler-number in the proccess. I got to $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{1 \cdot (1-1/n) \cdot (1-2/n) \cdot ... \cdot (1-(n-1)/n) }$$ by simply bringing the $n$ inside the n-th root sign, but I believe this is not the correct path.

I have no other ideas.

Comment: Thank you all for the interesting solutions, I never thought it could be approached in so many different ways.

Answer (score 7):

Let $a_n = \frac{n!}{n^n}$, then

$$\require{cancel}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \frac{n^n}{n!} = \frac{\cancel{(n+1)}}{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} \cancel{(n+1)}} = \frac{1}{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n} $$

Now $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{1}{e}$$

Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \color{#05f}{\frac{1}{e}}$$

Comment: Good ol' Stolz-C

Answer (score 6):

If $a_n = \sqrt[n]{n!}/n$, then

\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty} \log a_n &= \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\log n! - \log n\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n \log k - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n \log n\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n (\log k - \log n)\\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n \log \frac{k}{n}\\
&= \int_0^1 \log x\, dx\\
&= (x\log x - x)\bigg|_{x = 0}^1\\
&= -1.
\end{align}

Therefore, by continuity of $x \mapsto e^x$,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \frac{1}{e}.$$

Comment: How would you prove first that $ L \neq \infty $ exists? 
I think one needs the argument.

Comment: Yes, but the OP already knows that the limit exists. He was just trying to compute the limit without the use of Stirling.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it myself for a short time to show L exists:
Quotient criterium, finding an upper and lower bound and that a "the given sequence" is strictly monotonously increasing/decreasing, (which one does not matter) 
However I find those 2 methods not very creative, do you know immediately another one? (you don't have to)

Comment: I made changes to my answer that should answer your question. Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} \log a_n $ exists and the exponential function $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the log of this expression, and write it as a Riemann sum :

$$\ln\left( \sqrt[n]{ \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} 1-\frac{k}{n} } \right) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \ln(1-\frac{k}{n} )$$

Hence

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\ln\left( \sqrt[n]{ \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} 1-\frac{k}{n} } \right) = \int_{0}^1 \ln(1-x) dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Start as

$$ \frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n} = e^{ \frac{1}{n}\ln n! - \ln n } \sim e^{ \frac{n\ln n-n+1}{n}-\ln n }= e^{-1+1/n} \longrightarrow ...  $$